# Cannot install rbenv via homebrew (SSL Handshake)

Tags: ssl, homebrew, rbenv

Just re-installed Yosemite and I cannot install rbenv via homebrew

```
~  brew install rbenv ruby-build
==> Downloading https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/archive/v0.4.0.tar.gz 
########################################################################  100.0%
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
Error: Failed to download resource "rbenv"
Download failed:    https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/archive/v0.4.0.tar.gz
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Maybe due to the [DDoS attack on Github](https://status.github.com/messages)?

Comment: Yeah that is what I am starting to think.

Comment: Yep, that what it was.